# Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integration by parts formula

Tags: integration, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stieltjes-integral

Let $A,B$ be two right-continuous functions of finite variation. Then the integration by parts formula states:

$$
A_{t}B_{t} = A_0B_0+\int_{0}^{t} A_{-s}dB_s \, + \int_{0}^{t} B_{-s}dA_s + \sum_{ s\leq t}\triangle A_s \triangle B_s
$$

This question [The general integration by parts formula and the general change of variables formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839171/the-general-integration-by-parts-formula-and-the-general-change-of-variables-for) does most of the work. The last step is showing $\int_0^t \triangle A_s dB_s = \sum_{s\leq t}\triangle A_s \triangle B_s.$ Now, $\triangle A_s$ is $0$ everywhere except on at most a countable set of discontinuities of $A_s$. How does one approximate $\triangle A_s$ by simple functions and subsequently compute its integral wrt $B_s$? My intuition was the integral would be $0$ since $\triangle A_s$ is $0$ a.e., but I think the problem is it is not $0$ a.e. with respect to the measure $dB_s$.

Comment: Since $\Delta A_s$ is zero for all but countably many $s\geq0$ you only care about atoms of $dB_s$. The measure $dB_s$ has an atom at $s_0\geq0$ iff $B$ jumps at time $s_0$. The value of this point mass is precisely the size of the jump.

Comment: I note that the integration by parts formula given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839171/the-general-integration-by-parts-formula-and-the-general-change-of-variables-for
is for either both the functions A and B are right continuous or both left continuous.

Answer (score 0):

For left continuous functions there is a change of sign for the for the sum of jumps. Pl read the equation with the appropriate lower and upper scripts. I have a problem formatting the equation.

D is the set of points where both u and v are discontinuous.




 
  
   
    
     ∫
     
      [a,b]
    
    
     
      u
      +
     
     d
      λ
      v
     
     
   
   
  +
   
    
     ∫
     
      [a,b]
    
    
     
      v
      +
     
     d
      λ
      u
     
     
   
   
  =
   λ
   
    uv
  
  (
   
    [a,b]
  )+
   
    ∑
    
     x∈D
   
   
    
     λ
     u
    
    (x)
     λ
     v
    
    (x)

(Preserved post a user deleted to before answering it again.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please do not post the same answer twice

Comment: Please avoid posting multiple answers to the same question, unless your answers are *significantly* different from each other.  It appears to me that you may have posted multiple answers as a way of amending or improving previous answers---instead of posting a new answer, instead us the "Edit" link below your answer.